# NACL for VPC, used for web app best practices, allow all the traffic or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with public and privet subnets. A load balancer serves instances with web servers in private subnets.
I have security groups in place to allow only HTTP traffic for the balancer and only local HTTP traffic for instances.

Should I also set inbound/outbound rules for NACL on the VPC and each subnet?
Now the default seems to be to allow all the traffic.

Should I consider limiting traffic with NACL according to my needs (HTTP, ssh, etc)? or it's overkill or not very useful or overly complex?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed opinion-based but if you've got your Security Groups right adding NACLs between Public and Private subnets is an overkill.

Typically I use NACL mainly in 2 scenarios:

1. To separate Dev / Test / Qual / Prod subnets where we expect no traffic at all between them.
2. Or when it's a PCI / HIPAA / etc deployment and the auditor absolutely positively insists on having NACL between the subnets and can't be convinced otherwise.

In all other cases *well designed Security Groups are enough*. Where with *well designed* I mean mostly:

- SG's refering to other SG ID's and not to IP ranges (e.g. Web server SG permits tcp/443 from ALB SG ID, not from the public subnet IP range).
- Define Outbound rules to Deny unless needed otherwise.
- And of course only permit the required ports.

That way you can very well contain and restrict your networking traffic without having to use NACLs.

Hope that helps :)